# Blanks rows exported from SQL to excel

Tags: sql-server

When I export my query to excel .CSV I get a blank line after a filled line.

How can I delete the blank line in my query so that it is not exported to excel
[exmaple of outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAW0e.png)

```
SELECT 
   ID, 
   CASE 
      WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', q.outcome) <> 0 
      THEN SUBSTRING(q.outcome, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', q.outcome )  - 1) 
      ELSE q.outcome 
   END outcome
FROM (
        select 
           ID, 
           substring (Eventlog, CHARINDEX('to - usr', EventLog) + 16, LEN(Eventlog)) AS outcome
        from Summary
     )q
```

Comment: Did you mean export the results from SQL query execution to Excel? If so how do you export?? Copy paste from inside SSMS?

Comment: By not selecting them? F.e. add a where clause: `where len(rtrim(q.outcome))>0 `

Comment: Looking at the example outcome, those empty lines don't even have an id.  So it's probably not even related to the SQL, but the way you export the resultset to a file. Or could there be also a new line in that EventLog field?

Comment: Yes te eventlog field is a field with a lot of text. So there is an new line in this field. But how can i make sure that i do not export this line as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because there's a newline at the end of the outcome.

So you could remove all the Carriage Returns and Line Feed characters from it

```
...
ID, 
Replace(Replace(substring(Eventlog, CHARINDEX('to - usr', EventLog) + 16, LEN(Eventlog)),CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),'') AS outcome
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not shared the output of your query so not sure what data you are getting. Please try below sql:

```
SELECT ID,outcome FROM (
SELECT 
   ID, 
   CASE 
      WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', q.outcome) <> 0 
      THEN SUBSTRING(q.outcome, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', q.incoming )  - 1) 
      ELSE q.outcome 
   END outcome,
   ROW_NUMBER OVER() AS SNO
FROM (
        select 
           ID, 
           substring (Eventlog, CHARINDEX('to - usr', EventLog) + 16, LEN(Eventlog)) AS outcome
        from Summary
     )q
) A
WHERE mod(A.SNO,2) = 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help. I uploaded an example of the outcome